# How to get current url path in express with ejs

Tags: node.js

I want to search browser a query in Nodejs for How can I get current page URL Express with Ejs

Comment: Hi Deepak, could you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 12):

The protocol is available as req.protocol. [docs here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

```
var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
```

By using above example, you can get full page URL.

Answer (score 6):

Bhaurao's answer is good - but to give Deepak his full request (make the path available in EJS), you can do the following:

In your application code where you initialise Express:

```
let app=express();
app.use ((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.url = req.originalUrl;
    res.locals.host = req.get('host');
    res.locals.protocol = req.protocol;
    next();
});
```

Now, in your EJS, you should have access to the variables url, host and protocol. For example: `<%= url %>` will print the URL.

Hope that helps.